# How to count only the continuous repetitive sub-string in a given string python

Tags: python, substring

```
def count_overlapping(sequence, sub):
    counts = 0
    n = len(sub)
    while sub in sequence:
        counts += 1
        sequence = sequence[(sequence.find(sub) + n-1):]
    return counts
```

input: sequence = agatabttagataagataagatagatabagata

input: sub = agata

output: 3

This is the required output but my program is giving out 4.How do I ignore the non repetitive ones.

Someone please guide me here.

Comment: i found this, think it will help with
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41077268/python-find-repeated-substring-in-string/41077376

Comment: The formulation of the question is really unclear and partly self-contradictory. Do you mean that you're looking for the longest series of contiguous appearances of the substring? Or what exactly? Two answerers already read it in two completely different ways...

Comment: @ThierryLathuille  sorry for being unclear. I was trying to find the number of repetitions of a sub string in a string but only the ones which are continuous appearances.

I'll try to be more clear with my questions in future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest-but-no-so-efficient solution will be to multiply the substring each time, until you can't find it in the string anymore, and then you find the max repetitions:

```py
s = "agatabttagataagataagatagatabagata"
sub = "agata"

counts = 0
while sub * (counts+1) in s:
    counts += 1

print(counts)
```

This gives `3`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a regex based approach which uses `re.sub` to remove all repeating groups of the substring.  Then, to find the number of substrings which are present, we simply divide the difference in length by the length of the substring.

```
sequence = "agatabttagataagataagatagatabagata"
out = re.sub(r'(?:agata){2,}', '', sequence)
num = (len(sequence) - len(out)) / len('agata')
print(num)
```

This prints: `3`

Comment: Thank you very much. I guess this one also works for my problem but the below solution is much more fitting to my program.

Comment: @Drazer The answer you accepted is probably more efficient than what I have given you, but if you like or feel comfortable with regex, then this is a good option.